# Get the number of months from a date

Tags: mysql

So I have a MySQL table with a series of dates which formatted as follows:

```
2010-01-11 07:32:10
```

I am joining together several tables and want to know the number of months from that 
date until today. How can I do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) will for you:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,your_date_column,NOW()) FROM ....;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are finding is  [PERIOD_DIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_period-diff)